# How to pass selected, named arguments to Jinja2's include context?

Tags: templates, jinja2

Using Django templating engine I can include another partial template while setting a custom context using named arguments, like this:

```
{% include "list.html" with articles=articles_list1 only %}
{% include "list.html" with articles=articles_list2 only %}
```

As you may be supposing, `articles_list1` and `articles_list2` are two different lists, but I can reuse the very same `list.html` template which will be using the `articles` variable.

I'm trying to achieve the same thing using Jinja2, but I can't see what's the recommended way, as the `with` keyword is not supported.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Updated ***2021+***

`Included templates have access to the variables of the active context by default`. For more details about context behavior of imports and includes, see [Import Context Behavior](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.9.x/templates/#import-visibility).

From Jinja 2.2 onwards, you can mark an include with `ignore missing`; in which case Jinja will ignore the statement if the template to be included does not exist. When combined with `with` or `without context`, it must be placed *before* the context visibility statement. Here are some valid examples:

```
{% include "sidebar.html" ignore missing %}
{% include "sidebar.html" ignore missing with context %}
{% include "sidebar.html" ignore missing without context %}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the difference between `with context`, `without context`, and no statement (for Jinja2 used with Django)? Also versions without `ignore missing`?

Answer (score 168):

Jinja2 has the [`with`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#with-statement) keyword - it won't give you the same syntax as Django, and it may not work the way you anticipate but you could do this:

```
{% with articles=articles_list1 %}
    {% include "list.html" %}
{% endwith %}
{% with articles=articles_list2 %}
    {% include "list.html" %}
{% endwith %}
```

However, if `list.html` is basically just functioning as a way to create a list then you might want to change it to a [`macro`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#macros) instead - this will give you much more flexibility.

```
{% macro build_list(articles) %}
    <ul>
        {% for art in articles %}
            <li>{{art}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endmacro %}

{# And you call it thusly #}
{{ build_list(articles_list1) }}
{{ build_list(articles_list2) }}
```

To use this macro from another template, import it:

```
{% from "build_list_macro_def.html" import build_list %}
```

Comment: The link at the end points to the answer itself!

Comment: according to the docs this is now included in 2.9 and no longer needs to be loaded as an extension

Answer (score 78):

This way you can pass **multiple variables** to Jinja2 **Include** statement - (by splitting variables by comma inside **With** statement):

```
            {% with var_1=123, var_2="value 2", var_3=500 %}
                {% include "your_template.html" %}
            {% endwith %}
```

Comment: and then in the .html how to access the variables?

Comment: @AhmedHasn. {{var_name}}

Answer (score 50):

For readers in 2017+, Jinja as of `2.9` includes the `with` statement by default. No extension necessary.

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#with-statement

> In older versions of Jinja (before 2.9) it was required to enable this feature with an extension. It’s now enabled by default.

Comment: Well I find myself in 2017 and it doesn't work. Bother with providing a link?

Comment: @Pithikos http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#with-statement 
"In older versions of Jinja (before 2.9) it was required to enable this feature with an extension. It’s now enabled by default."

Answer (score 2):

Another option, without plugins, is to use macros and include them from another file:

*file **macro.j2***

```
{% macro my_macro(param) %}
  {{ param }}
{% endmacro %}
```

*file **main.j2***

```
{% from 'macro.j2' import my_macro %}

{{ my_macro(param) }}
```