# How to pass blocks to include statement in Jinja2

Tags: flask, jinja2

I need to pass block from base template to included template with context, but don't want
overlapping of this blocks in base template. 
For example, I have couple templates

**header.html**

```
<header>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</header>
```

**body1.html**

```
{% include   "test_header.html" ignore missing with context %}
{% block title %}Title1{% endblock %}
<body>
    Hello
</body>
```

**body2.html**

```
{% include   "test_header.html" ignore missing with context %}
{% block title %}Title2{% endblock %}
<body>
    Hello
</body>
```

When I try to render body1.html, title of page renames to "Title1", but block title renders twice and shows Title1 in body. How I can pass this context exactly for include statement?

Comment: Generally speaking, you have a use case of `extends`, not `include`. I'd create a `base.html` with included `header.html`. Then I'd extend body1 and body2 from base.

Answer (score 2):

The method to include dynamic content like the title is usually {{ ... }}, while {% ... %} is for control statements (for loops, if statements, blocks, etc). You might construct your specific templates like the following:

**base.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

As stated by @alecxe, you should `extends` off a base template.

**body1.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block body %}
Hello!
{% endblock %}
```

**body2.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block body %}
Hi!
{% endblock %}
```

The title should be passed to the template with `render_template()` in the view.

**view.py excerpt**

```
@app.route('/body1')
def body1():
    title = "Body 1 Title"
    return render_template("body1.html", title = title)

@app.route('/body2')
def body2():
    title = "Body 2 Title"
    return render_template("body2.html", title = title)
```

If you greatly wanted to vary the header between templates, you could also replace `<title>{{title}}</title>` with `{% block header %}{% endblock %}` in `base.html`.  Your `body1.html` could then look like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block header %}
<title>{{title}}</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
Hello!
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Blocks don't work in included templates. They are only valid in child / parent template relationships. How about something like...

sections.html

```
{% with section_data=section_data %}
{% include 'section.html' %}
{% endwith %}
```

section.html:

```
{% for section in section_data %}
  <h2>{{ section.title }}</h2>
  <div>
    {{ section.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

See: [How to pass selected, named arguments to Jinja2's include context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404990/how-to-pass-selected-named-arguments-to-jinja2s-include-context)

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/b7eh21/how_do_i_pass_blocks_or_information_into_an/