# Python Flask: variables inside {% include ...%}

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to pass a variable inside an `include` statement:

****init**.py:**

```
@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template("index.html", content="about.html")
```

**index.html:**

```
{% include {{ content }} %}
```

does not work!

Comment: How do you want your site to look? This seems like backend work to me, not the remit of jinja

Comment: I feel almost certain that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

As this thread pops up via the google search and the answer is pretty straight forward:

Just do not use the `{{}}` syntax inside the include statement. So instead of

```
{% include {{ content }} %}
```

use

```
{% include content %}
```

which will evaluate the variable set in `render_template`

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been asked and answered.

[How to pass selected, named arguments to Jinja2's include context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404990/how-to-pass-selected-named-arguments-to-jinja2s-include-context)

Use utility processor to pass in variables to your template.

With the following code, foo will be defined and available to all of your templates.

```
@app.context_processor
def utility_processor():
    rval = dict()
    
    rval['foo']   = 'bar'
```

Comment: What's this got to do with `{% include %}` for template inheritance?

Comment: ‘index.html’ consists of the usual html code **+** an ‘include’ statement which inherits code from about.html. But instead writing ‘{% include “about.html“ %}’, I wanna pass the variable ‘content’ into the statement.

Comment: @shrewmouse No, it hasn't been asked. The post you are referring to is about passing a variable thru a template to another template instead of using it directly in the `include` statement.