# Jinja pass argument into include

Tags: javascript, html, flask, jinja2

I would like to reuse the following code several times:

**body.html file**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 text-dark">
            ...
            <p>Download: <a href="{{ link }}" class="link-secondary">link</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <iframe src="{{ link }}" style="min-height:88vh;width:100%"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the **sfa.html** file I want to use **body.html** file and passing the the following argument: `"{{url_for('static', filename='pdf/Lorem-Ipsum.pdf')}}"`

**sfa.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

{% include 'header.html'%} //works fine

</head>
<body>

{% include 'nav.html'%} //works fine

{% include 'body.html' with 'link' : "{{url_for('static', filename='pdf/Lorem-Ipsum.pdf')}}" %} //here is the problem

</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the following error in the browser: `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'with'`

What is the problem with my code?

Answer (score -1):

In your case, i think you'll have to do something like this :

```
{% with link="{{url_for('static', filename='pdf/Lorem-Ipsum.pdf')}}" %}
  {% include "body.html" %}
{% endwith %}
```

[Documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#with-statement)

[Other thread about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404990/how-to-pass-selected-named-arguments-to-jinja2s-include-context)

Comment: Is your flask server set to serve static files and your pdf at {flask_app_folder}/static/pdf/Lorem-Ipsum.pdf ?

Comment: Yes, the pdf location is the following: {flask_app_folder}/static/pdf/Lorem-Ipsum.pdf